# Writing tests against local firestore emulator using the admin SDK with no auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Edit: it's essentially an issue of the firebase-emulator docs. See discussion [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2602).

---

I'm trying to directly access a Firestore instance running on the local emulator with the nodejs admin SDK. Minimal example:

```js
// test.js
const admin = require("firebase-admin"); // version 9.1.1
admin.firestore().collection('foo').add({ a: 1 });
```

Then just `$ node test.js` to see if it works.

The only doc I can find regarding this is this [one sentence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#admin_sdks), which tells me to set an environmental variable, so I did, something like this:

```
$ FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST='localhost:1003' node test.js
```

But I get an error message `Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment.` But I *am* inside my filebase project folder. What am I missing? My eventual goal is to write unit tests to test my server code that uses firestore. The server is running on cloud functions, and currently I am able to trigger the function from within the test suites which can successfully read/write to the local DB, but that's too convoluted for writing tests.

firebase.json:

```json
{
  ...
  "emulators": {
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true,
      "port": 1000
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 1001
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 1002
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 1003
    }
  }
}
```

(I've tried each of these 4 ports, none worked)

Answer (score 1):

When emulator is run with command `firebase emulators:start` you will get ports for emulated features ex.:

```
 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ ✔  All emulators ready! View status and logs at http://localhost:4000 │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┐
│ Emulator  │ Host:Port      │ View in Emulator UI             │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Functions │ localhost:5001 │ http://localhost:4000/functions │
├───────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────┤
│ Firestore │ localhost:3000 │ http://localhost:4000/firestore │
└───────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┘
  Other reserved ports: 4400, 4500
Issues? Report them at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues and attach the *-debug.log files.
```

Than using the same link I created minimal example:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin"); // version 9.1.1
admin.initializeApp();
var db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({
    host: "localhost:3000",
    ssl: false
});
admin.firestore().collection('foo').add({ a: 1 })
.then( (r) => console.log("document added: ",r.path) )
.catch( (e) => console.log("error: ",e) );
```

Note that first app instance has to be created with `initializeApp` method and than set the path to your emulator. However I guess there are many other ways to do this. If successful this will show path to created doc. I didn't use any additional setup.

Comment: Mine still doesn't work. I suspect I have a different setup than you, but it seems everything is the same. 1. If you `console.log(process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST)` in your working code, what's the output? 2. if you remove the `db.settings({...})` part and try again, what error message do you get? Thanks!

Comment: And also, if you `console.log(process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)` in your working code, does it output a path that you've previously set which is a service account credential json?

Comment: I found my problem: I need to supply the "projectID" in db.settings({}). I don't know why yours worked without it. Did you configure it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that the Firebase Emulators like being given a dummy project id. I use something like `bunny` in my projects, to make it seem funny.

Launch the emulator with:

```
$ firebase emulators:start --project=bunny --only auth,functions,firestore
```

The reality is more complicated, though. For a real world example, you can check out http://github.com/akauppi/GroundLevel-firebase-es

Comment: Using the real project id is recommended, unless you're not using the emulator UI to visualize your data && you're not visiting the db from functions. In short, functions and web UI always use the real id, so they'll visit different instances of db than bunny.

Comment: @ZYinMD Could you give a link to where it's recommended?

Comment: the link in the first line of OP

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I agree with @akauppi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67247874/2928853). This is a snippet from the firebase emulators docs:

> When connecting to the Authentication emulator, you will need to specify a project ID. You can pass a project ID to initializeApp directly or set the GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variable. Note that you do not need to use your real Firebase project ID; the Authentication emulator will accept any project ID.